# Array with XSLT 1.0

Tags: arrays, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a simple array below

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="array">
        <Item>One</Item>
        <Item>Two</Item>
        <Item>Three</Item>
    </xsl:variable>
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:value-of select="$array"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Which displays

```
OneTwoThree
```

However, when I try

```
<xsl:value-of select="$array[0]"/>
```

The entire page breaks

Any idea how I can access "One" in my array?

Answer (score 1):

First, there are no arrays in XSLT 1.0. Your variable is a [result tree fragment](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#section-Result-Tree-Fragments) with 3 `Item` child elements.

Result tree fragments cannot be parsed directly; you need to convert them to a node-set first, using an extension function supported by your processor - for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="array">
        <Item>One</Item>
        <Item>Two</Item>
        <Item>Three</Item>
    </xsl:variable>
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($array)/Item[1]"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Alternatively, you could bypass the limitation by parsing the stylesheet directly:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="array">
        <Item>One</Item>
        <Item>Two</Item>
        <Item>Three</Item>
    </xsl:variable>
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:value-of select="document('')//xsl:variable[@name='array']/Item[1]"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Do note that node numbering starts at 1, not 0.